# set properties and union method

Tags: python, hash, set, tuples, union

I have a question regarding set.
I have the following code that illustrate my question.

```
def f2( s ):
    return { c.upper() for c in s if c.isalpha() }

print f2( "A r'a|ccCc^#zZ" )
print f2( "A r'a|ccCc^#zZ" ).union( [( 'B', )] )
print f2( "A r'a|ccCc^#zZ" ).union( [( 'T', )])
```

The result is:

```
set(['A', 'C', 'R', 'Z'])
set(['A', ('B',), 'C', 'R', 'Z'])
set(['A', 'C', 'R', 'Z', ('T',)])
```

Why is the set order in that order ?
In the first time I can guess it is ordered according to the A-Z (hash function?)
But why there is a difference in the position of the tuple in the other lines ?

Answer (score 0):

[Sets have no order.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

From the documentation:

> The sets module provides classes for constructing and manipulating **unordered** collections of unique elements. Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates from a sequence, and computing standard math operations on sets such as intersection, union, difference, and symmetric difference.